# Zend Framework: Get View as Return value

Tags: zend-framework, view, frameworks, return

I habe a controller and an action to print a website. Now I want to use this output to create a pdf. 
I dont want to do the same work again in an other action. How can I get the output from the view to use in like: 
$output = ... hier my controller/action/ and parameters

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Easy job.

In your ControllerAction use:

```
// change PHTML FIle for your Action
$output = $this->view->render('controller/youraction.phtml');
```